# MDX query - Average

Tags: mdx

I would like to calculate average using a numeric value in dimension instead of using a measure. Is that possible?

Also I would like to know whether average can be calculated with a dimension that is categorized with another dimension.

Comment: Please can you add the `mdx` you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `Avg` function on`MSDN`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx

It gives several examples of using it with numeric expressions such as the following:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.[Avg Gross Profit Margin] AS
   Avg(
      Descendants(
         [Ship Date].[Fiscal].CurrentMember, 
            [Ship Date].[Fiscal].[Date]
      ), 
      Measures.[Gross Profit Margin]
   )
SELECT
   Measures.[Avg Gross Profit Margin] ON COLUMNS,
      [Ship Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].[FY 2003].Children ON ROWS
FROM
   [Adventure Works]
```